GitHub Actions does not execute the commands on cmd
I am trying to execute some simple tests running GitHub Actions on Windows 10 runners.
The actions I'd like to run is very simple:
Name: Test
run-name: ${{ gitea.actor }} is under test
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: windows
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build
        shell: cmd.exe
        run: ls

But as an output, I have the correct on for the job setup and the checkout and only the first header lines of the cmd.exe:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4529]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I have tried other simple commands but always getting the same output. What's happening?

ls is not a windows command, use dir instead.
And as said in this comment usually you should specify shell, but generally you'll get an error notifying you that shell parameter is missing.

You need to specify which shell you're trying to use, bash/pwsh(powershell) depending on which os you're using.
Name: Test
run-name: ${{ gitea.actor }} is under test
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: windows
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build
        shell: pwsh
        run: Get-ChildItem -Recurse

